# Internet Explorer Full Page background

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

I currently am working on a site with a full-screen flash video background - http://polivision.tv/test.html

It is working in most browsers, except apparently IE (I am working on a mac).

Apparently the only problem is the flash video is not playing.

I put this in the body:

```
<div class="zone-home"> 

<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" id="background-vid" align="middle">

  <param name="LOOP" value="true" />
  <param name="allowfullscreen" value="false" />
  <param name="quality" value="high" />
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#000" /> 
  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
  <embed src="background-vid.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="black" width="100%" height="100%" name="background-vid" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" loop="true"></embed>
</object>
```

and use this to make it full screen:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $windowW = $(window).width();
var $windowH = $(window).height();
var $one = "object#background-vid";
var $two = ".zone-home";
$($one).attr({ width: $windowW, height: $windowH });
$($two).attr({ width: $windowW, height: $windowH });

$(window).bind("resize", function(){
    var $windowW = $(window).width();
    var $windowH = $(window).height();
    var $one = "object#background-vid";
    var $two = ".zone-home";
    $($one).attr({width:$windowW, height: $windowH });
    $($two).attr({ width: $windowW, height: $windowH });
});
});
```

Thanks in advance,
Shoma

Comment: Can you show a live link? Does the tested system have a current Flash plugin installed?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a script missing: http://polivision.tv/resources/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js.  This may be causing IE to stop rendering because it throws a JavaScript error.  I would check your 404s using Firebug in Firefox and correct them.  This might solve the problem in IE.